# React Hooks: How can I use multiple instances of my useToggle hook on one component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

**Overview:**

I've created a custom `useToggle` react hook and I want to use two instances in one component. A toggle for the "Privacy Policy" and a toggle for the "Terms and Conditions."

**Question**

How can I use the same `useToggle` hook to get different constants for each useToggle hook such as the following below. A solution for `[isToggled, toggle]` or `{ isToggled, toggle }` works. Object destructuring is preferred if it is possible.

```js
const privacyPolicy = [isToggled, toggle] = useToggle();
const terms = [isToggled, toggle] = useToggle();


<button title="Privacy Policy" onClick={privacyPolicy.toggle} />
<button title="Terms & Conditions" onClick={terms.toggle} />
```

**useToggle.ts**

```
// Imports: Dependencies
import { useCallback, useState } from 'react';

// Imports: TypeScript Types
import { TReactHookUseToggle } from '@jefelewis/unison-types';

// React Hook: Use Toggle
export const useToggle = (initialState: boolean = false): TReactHookUseToggle => {
  // React Hooks: State
  const [isToggled, setIsToggled] = useState<boolean>(initialState);

  // Toggle
  const toggle: () => void = useCallback((): void => setIsToggled((prevState: boolean) => !prevState), []);

  return [isToggled, toggle];
};
```

Comment: ...just call the hook functions different names based on what kind on thing they're toggling? i.e. `const [isPrivacyPolicyToggled, togglePrivacyPolicy] = useToggle();`, repeat for each toggle; no overlaps

Answer (score 1):

To give them different names, do so when you destructure the array:

```
const [privacyIsToggled, togglePrivacy] = useToggle();
const [termsIsToggled, toggleTerms] = useToggle();

<button title="Privacy Policy" onClick={togglePrivacy} />
<button title="Terms & Conditions" onClick={toggleTerms} />
```